# How to add Hover on image.?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a hover effect in css3, but, whenever i hover over image a straight ling generates right next to the image during the transition of .5s

```
<img src="img/nat-9.jpg" alt="Person on a tour" class="story__img" />

img {height: 100%; transition: all 0.5s; transform: translateX(-4rem) scale(1.4);}
```

As shown in image

[image]

Comment: Hi kindly post a complete code here so i will help you after reviewing your code

Comment: Show us your code please. Otherwise we can't help you

Answer (score 1):

Here is the hover effect, you are looking for.

```css
.story-wrapper .image-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    shape-outside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}



.story-wrapper .image-wrapper img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    transition: 0.9s;
    object-fit:cover;
}

.story-wrapper .image-wrapper .hover-text label {
    width: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.story-wrapper .image-wrapper .hover-text span {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 26px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

 .story-wrapper .image-wrapper .hover-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    left: 50%;
    transition: top 0.9s;
    top: 179%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.story-wrapper:hover img {
    filter: blur(2px);
    transform: scale(1.4);
    transition: 0.9s;
}

.story-wrapper:hover .hover-text {
    transition: 0.9s top;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="story-wrapper">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
                     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1021693/pexels-photo-1021693.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">

                    <div class="hover-text">
                        <label><span>MARY SMITH</span></label>
                    </div>

        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help! The problem was solved by using `overflow: hidden` property on its parent element, and sorry for not posting the whole code, because I thought the problem is with that chunk of code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by using `overflow: hidden` property on its parent element.